# Trigger showing a hidden div when tablesorter table is showing last row

Tags: jquery, tablesorter

Essentially, I can't find how I could determine if my TS table **is showing** the very last available row. I need to be able to show a 'Add Client' button / div under my table when A) the table is showing all available items (no more pages accessible), or B) when the user has moved to the last page of the table.

Can this be done with Mottie's tablesorter ?

Here's my javascript to load the tablesorter..

```
function loadTSTable(table2load){
    
  /* <table id="tableX"> tag to specify different tables to be threated by the Tablesorter */

  var $table1 = $('#' + table2load); 

  /***************************
   * main tablesorter config
   ***************************/
  $table1.tablesorter( {
  theme : "bootstrap",

  widthFixed: true,

  /* click on column header a 3rd time to disable sorting, else need to ctrl+click */
  sortReset: false,


  // widget code contained in the jquery.tablesorter.widgets.js file
  // use the zebra stripe widget if you plan on hiding any rows (filter widget)
  // the uitheme widget is NOT REQUIRED!
  // PROY: eventually also look at the Output Widget
  widgets : [ "filter", "columnSelector", "columns", "zebra", "mark"],

  widgetOptions : {
    // using the default zebra striping class name, so it actually isn't included in the theme variable above
    // this is ONLY needed for bootstrap theming if you are using the filter widget, because rows are hidden
    zebra : ["even", "odd"],

    // class names added to columns (need 'columns' widget) when sorted
    columns: [ "primary", "secondary", "tertiary" ],

    /* -------------------------
     * FILTER WIDGET OPTIONS
     * -------------------------*/

    // class added to filtered rows (rows that are not showing); needed by pager plugin
    // proy is this needed !?
    filter_filteredRow   : 'filtered',

    // reset filter button
    filter_reset : ".reset",

    // auto-hide filter row, popup when moused-over
    filter_hideFilters: false,

    // GLOBAL SEARCH FACILITY
    // filter_anyMatch replaced! Instead use the filter_external option
    // Set to use a jQuery selector (or jQuery object) pointing to the
    // external filter (column specific or any match)
    filter_external : '.search',

    // add a default column filter type "~{query}" to make fuzzy searches default to the first name column
    //filter_defaultFilter: { 1 : '~{query}' },
    filter_defaultFilter: {},

    // include column filters
    filter_columnFilters: true,

    // save filter data, even if page is reloaded, they will still be there!
    filter_saveFilters : false,

    // ignore case in search
    filter_ignoreCase: true,

    // extra css class name (string or array) added to the filter element (input or select)
    //filter_cssFilter: "form-control form-control-sm p-1",

    // OR, to set specific css to specific columns:
      filter_cssFilter: [
        'form-control form-control-sm p-1',
        'form-control form-control-sm p-1',
        'form-control form-control-sm p-1',
        'form-control form-control-sm p-1'        
      ],

      // Add select box to columns (zero-based index)
      // each option has an associated function that returns a boolean
      // function variables:
      // e = exact text from cell
      // n = normalized value returned by the column parser
      // f = search filter input value
      // i = column index (zero-based index)
      filter_functions : {
      },

     /* -------------------------
      * MARK WIDGET OPTIONS
      * see: https://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/example-widget-mark.html
      * -------------------------*/      
  
     // *** mark widget only settings
      mark_tsUpdate : 'markUpdate',
      mark_tsIgnore : {
        // don't highlight 'artistic' and 'status' columns
        //4: true,
        //6: true,
      },
      // *** default settings for non-regular expression searches only
      mark_accuracy: 'partially',
      mark_caseSensitive: false,
      mark_diacritics: true,
      mark_separateWordSearch: true,
      mark_synonyms: {},
    
      // *** settings that apply to regex & non-regular expression searches
      mark_acrossElements: false,
      mark_className: '',
      mark_debug: false,
      mark_element: 'mark',
      mark_exclude: [],
      mark_iframes: false,
      mark_log: console,
    
      // callback functions
      mark_done: function(totalMatches) {},
      mark_each: function(element) {},
      mark_filter: function(node, term, totalMatches, matches) {
        // "matches" parameter is not defined for regular expression searches
        return true;
      },
      mark_noMatch: function(termNotFound) {},
    }
  });

  /***************************
   * setup Pager
   ***************************/
  $table1.tablesorterPager({
  // target the pager markup - see the HTML block below
  container: $(".ts-pager-" + table2load),

  // target the pager page select dropdown - choose a page
  cssGoto  : ".pagenum-" + table2load,
  
  // target the page size selector
  cssPageSize: '.pagesize-' + table2load,

  // remove rows from the table to speed up the sort of large tables.
  // setting this to false, only hides the non-visible rows; needed if you plan to add/remove rows with the pager enabled.
  removeRows: false,

  // output string - default is '{page}/{totalPages}';
  // possible variables: {page}, {totalPages}, {filteredPages}, {startRow}, {endRow}, {filteredRows} and {totalRows}
  output: '{startRow} - {endRow} / {filteredRows} ({totalRows})'

  });

  /***************************
   * show error message if no data
   ***************************/
  $table1.on('filterEnd filterReset pagerComplete', function(e, table){
      var fr, table = this;
      if (table.config.pager) {
          $.tablesorter.showError(table); // remove all prior error rows from the table thead, if any
          fr = table.config.pager.filteredRows;
          if (fr === 0) {
          
            if(table2load == 'tblAllProducers'){
              msg = "No clients were found in this list.\nYou can request to add a new client below.";
              $('#addClient').addClass('d-block'); // show 'Add Client' button
            }
            else {              
              msg = "No clients were found in this list. Try searching in all clients.";
            }
          
            $.tablesorter.showError(table, msg);
            
            // hotfix: since error messages are placed in thead, force a different font-size then what defaults in thead for text-size! 
            $('.tablesorter-errorRow').css("font-size", "large");            
          }
      }
  });

}
```

Cheers! Pat

EDIT: So, partial fix:

```
  if (fr === 0) {
    ...
  }
  // show 'Add Client' button if we're on last page          
  else {
    // page variable is zero-indexed current page number;  totalPages is well, total pages! 
    if( (table.config.pager.totalPages - table.config.pager.page ) === 1)  {
      $('#addClient').addClass('d-block'); // show 'Add Client' button
    }
  }
```

NEW EDIT: Trying to implement the 'tablesorter-initialized' method, I also tried with the following to make the table show the DIV if it's on the last page upon table load:

```
$table1.tablesorter( {

  // if we're already showing last page, show 'Add Client' button
  initialized : function(table) {
    console.warn(table.config.pager); // shows me 'undefined'
    console.warn(table.config); // shows me all config properties, and 'pager' IS in them!!?

    if( (table.config.pager.totalPages - table.config.pager.page ) === 1)  {
      $('#addClient').addClass('d-block'); // show 'Add Client' button
    }  
  },

  ...
});
```

It doesn't work. For some reasons, **table.config.pager** will be `undefined`, BUT the output of just **table.config** DOES seem to have the pager property! See image:

[image]

I'm a little puzzled here :(

EDIT 3 : Still no go with the pagerInitialized event. Here's my code:

```
  $table1.on('filterEnd filterReset pagerComplete pagerInitialized', function(e, table){
      
      var fr, table = this;
      
      if (table.config.pager) {
          $.tablesorter.showError(table); // remove all prior error rows from the table thead, if any
          fr = table.config.pager.filteredRows;
          
          if (fr === 0) {
          
            if(table2load == 'tblAllProducers'){
              msg = localejs.gettext("No clients were found in this list.\nYou can request to add a new client below.");
              $('#addClient').addClass('d-block'); // show 'Add Client' button if we've found no match through filter
            }
            else {              
              msg = localejs.gettext("No clients were found in this list. Try searching in all clients.");
            }
          
            $.tablesorter.showError(table, msg);                       
          }
          
          // show 'Add Client' button if we're on last page          
          else {
            // page variable is zero-indexed current page number;  totalPages is well, total pages! 
            if( (table.config.pager.totalPages - table.config.pager.page ) === 1)  {
              $('#addClient').addClass('d-block'); // show 'Add Client' button
            }
          }
      }
  });
```

EDIT 4: Solution

```
$table1.bind('pagerInitialized', function(event, options) {
  // page variable is zero-indexed current page number
  if( (options.totalPages - options.page ) == 1)  {
    $('#addClient').addClass('d-block'); // show 'Add Client' button
  }
});


$table1.tablesorter(...);
```

Comment: Add an `else` block to the `if (fr === 0)` and check the [current page](https://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/#variable-pager-page) against the [total pages](https://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/#variable-pager-totalpages). These values change based on the filter.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Mottie! See EDIT I just did please. I still have one glitch though : if the page loads and we're already on last page, then the DIV won't be showed...  Know where else I'd do this same check to make it run after table is loaded? Cheers!

Comment: In your `$table1.on(...)` list, include the [`tablesorter-initialized`](https://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/#tablesorter-initialized) event.

Comment: Hmm didn't work. I just tried, but even with the added 'tablesorter-initialized' event, doesn't seem to kick in after page has loaded... (?)

Comment: I've added another EDIT in the post. If you don't mind having a look :) Thanks a million for your time :)

Comment: Oh, the pager is initialized _after_ tablesorter, so use [`pagerInitialized`](https://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/#pagerinitialized) instead.

Comment: Arghh! I thought it could be something like that, BUT it's still not working! Doesn't kick in... what the heck is going on here :(( See edit 3...

Comment: Found the solution, based on the pagerInitialized... Note that adding it to my $table1.on(...) *does not* work. I needed to use the .bind() method BEFORE my $table1.tablesorter(...). See edit 4. Cheers for your help!